# Applescript - reload webpage till HTML contains specific text

Tags: html, search, applescript, reload

I want to create an applescript.

I need to automatically reload the current webpage in Chrome (or Safari) till there appears some specific keyword in HTML. After it finds this keyword, stop reloading.

The webpage has a zone with an advertisement. And I need to reload the page as long as I can see some specific advertisement. This means that the keyword `adPraha` is in the HTML.

Could you help me, please?

```
set keyword to "adPraha"
tell application "Safari"   
    -- get the current window
    set myWindow to (get current tab of window 1)

    repeat
        do JavaScript "window.location.reload()" in myWindow


        -- wait for the page to load        
        repeat until ((do JavaScript "document.readyState;" in myWindow) is equal to "complete")
            delay 0.5
        end repeat

        set pageContent to text of myWindow

        if pageContent contains keyword then

        else

        end if

        delay 2 -- wait a bit before running again

    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: What is actually wrong with this script? It appears to work, to me. I added a display dialog between the `if/else` and another between `else/end if`, and the script successfully detected when `pageContent` contained `keyword`. Are you looking for the `exit repeat` command? Put it between `else/endif` or replace “contains keyword” with “does not contain keyword”, and it will exit the repeat on loss of the keyword.

Answer (score 1):

This script will let you know with a dialog box that the page has detected the keyword. It only works with Safari. Google Chrome executes JavaScript a bit differently:

```
tell application "Safari"

    set keyword to "adPraha"
    repeat
        set myWindow to current tab of first window
        activate

        do JavaScript "window.location.reload()" in myWindow

        repeat while (do JavaScript "document.readyState" in document 1) is not "complete"
            delay 0.5
        end repeat

        set pageContent to do JavaScript ("window.document.documentElement.outerHTML") in myWindow

        if pageContent contains keyword then
            display dialog "found it"
            exit repeat
        end if
        delay 2 -- wait a bit before running again
    end repeat
end tell
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: Thank you very much! This work with words in web. But I would like to search keyword in HTML source code. Some tags or some values of HTML in web. Is is possible to search it? I have found some script for parse HTML but it cant do it.